# Register .NET Core singleton service via annotation

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

**Is there any way to autowire (automatically register) singleton services to a C# DI container** ([Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)) **by annotation?**

E.g. something like [ProvidedIn option in @Injectable() annotation in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service), @injectable() annotation in [InversifyJS (Node.js)](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS), autowiring in [Spring (Java)](https://www.javatpoint.com/autowiring-in-spring) or autowiring in [Symfony Framework (PHP)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)**?**

See Angular example below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

At this time I have to add each singleton service to ServiceCollection manually this way (and forget to do it sometimes):

```
internal static ServiceProvider SetupDi()
{
    return new ServiceCollection() // Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection.ServiceCollection()
        .AddDbContext<DbContext>()
        .AddSingleton<ServiceA>()
        .AddSingleton<ServiceB>();
}
```

The desired equivalent solution would be something like this:

```
internal static ServiceProvider SetupDi()
{
    return new ServiceCollection() // Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection.ServiceCollection()
        .AddDbContext<DbContext>();
}

[Injectable()]
public class ServiceA
{
}

[Injectable()]
public class ServiceB
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use Scrutor to add assembly scanning capabilities to the
>   ASP.NET Core DI container.

For details you can check this blog https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/

Answer (score 1):

No, and that's actually by-design.

The whole point of DI is that there are no *surprises* with how your program is configured: everything you configure in `ConfigureServices` (your in your case, `SetupDi`) is exactly what you get at runtime. By using attributes to configure DI then that would introduce "non-local effects" and it would be much harder to track-down bugs introduced by incorrect or misconfigured dependencies caused by an errant attribute.

(To that extent, I disagree with Angular's design - but that's off-topic).

(I also feel that .NET Core's DI system is also imperfect - too many necessary details are hidden behind DI injection extension-methods that you need to use ILSpy or Reflector to peer into).

As a workaround, you *can* "test" your DI services at app startup to ensure everything is configured by reflecting over every `IService` in your project and trying to instantiate the implementation.

Here's the code I use in my ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core projects to verify DI is thoroughly configured:

```
internal static void TestAllServices( IServiceProvider sp )
{
    Assembly[] mySolutionAssemblies = new[]
    {
        typeof(FromAssemblyX.Foobar).Assemby,
        typeof(FromAssemblyY.Foobar).Assemby,
        typeof(FromAssemblyZ.Foobar).Assemby,
    };

    List<Type> allServiceInterfaceTypes = mySolutionAssemblies
        .SelectMany( ass => ass.GetTypes() )
        .Where( t => t.IsInterface && t.IsPublic )
        .Where( /* Filter out interfaces you don't want to verify here */ )
        .ToList();

    foreach( Type serviceInterfaceType in serviceInterfaceTypes )
    {
        try
        {
            Object implementation = sp.GetRequiredService( serviceInterfaceType );
            if( implementation is IDisposable disp ) disp.Dispose();
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            // Log an error or throw or set a breakpoint here
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Don't pass in your "real" `IServiceProvider` into `TestAllServices` - instead create a separate `IServiceProvider` instance, because this method will dispose any implementation that implements `IDisposable`, even if they're singletons.
- I recommend having this code wrapped in `#if DEBUG` to ensure it doesn't go into production.
- A major downside to .NET Core's default DI system is that it's impossible to statically differentiate "scoped" service implementations from singletons and transient services - you could work-around this by adding marker-interfaces on the service implementations and handling those accordingly.

  - Though to be fair, [ASP.NET Core *can* validate your scoped dependencies by itself](https://andrewlock.net/new-in-asp-net-core-3-service-provider-validation/) - but you need to use `.AddControllersAsServices()`.

Another note:

If you *really* wanted to, you could use the same `allServiceInterfaceTypes` technique above inside your `ConfigureServices` method to enumerate over all interface and detect all types implementing each interface, and discover any custom attributes on those types and automatically register them in the DI container - but I don't recommend doing that because reflection is slower than using DI as-intended - and configuring things like factory-methods would be much harder.